# Parallax and vibrate background image with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I need background image parallax and vibrate little bit when scrolling with mouse.

Background position is working with jQuery's `css()` function but not vibrating.

When ii firebug it result is

```
<div data-speed="10" data-type="background" style="height: 1000px; 
background-position: 50% 0px; animation: 0s ease 0s normal none 1 NaNpx;" 
class="parallax-container" id="intro">
```

#### I am using jQuery's  code for this, and testing in Mozilla.

```
/*parallex backgound*/
$glob('div[data-type="background"]').each( function() {
    var $bgobj = $glob(this); // assigning the object
    $glob(window).scroll( function() {
        var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / 10);
        var coords = '50% '+ (yPos) + 'px';
        $bgobj.css({'background-position': coords}).animate({
            '-webkit-animation': 'vibrateAnim 1s ease', /* Safari 4+ */
            '-moz-animation':    'vibrateAnim 1s ease', /* Fx 5+ */
            '-o-animation':      'vibrateAnim 1s ease', /* Opera 12+ */
            'animation':         'vibrateAnim 1s ease'  /* IE 10+ */
        },500);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="intro" class="parallax-container" style='height:1000px;' data-type="background" data-speed="10">
    <div id="mainTitleText" class="top-content">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
    </div><!-- mainTitleText -->
</div><!--home-->
```

**CSS:**

```
@-moz-keyframes vibrateAnim {
    0%   { top: -10px; }
    10%  { top:  10px; }
    20%  { top: -10px; }
    30%  { top:  10px; }
    40%  { top: -10px; }
    50%  { top:  10px; }
    60%  { top: -10px; }
    70%  { top:  10px; }
    80%  { top: -10px; }
    90%  { top:  10px; }
    100% { top: -10px; }
}
```

**DEMO:**
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kk4xK/)

I need as in link **https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT**

Comment: sir i got solution with your code.. please close.. thanx for your support..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6Jej/1/show)

(Tip: Remove `/show/` in URL to access jsFiddle *Edit* Page).

Consider using the [**jQuery Vibrate**](http://www.dev4web.eu/projects/jquery.vibrate/#about) plugin in *your Parallax website*. The [**parallax website**](https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT) you mentioned in comments is using a [**custom written parallax script**](https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/js/LandRoverSite.js) for that site, so no plugin is available.

The above jsFiddle uses parallax plugin [**jQuery Parallax v1.1.3**](https://github.com/IanLunn/jQuery-Parallax) along with it's [**revised demo**](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/), modified with an extra vibrating [**trainers**](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/images/trainers.png) footwear object.

The benefit of this vibrate plugin is that it has interaction with the mouse, to stop vibrating when the mouse is over any text when used with `reverse` option. That is useful so visitors can ready message clearly.

*Side note: In the jsFiddle, the vibrating object is in between 2 other elements, so the mouseover will not apply in that case due to DOM layout order.*

```js
$('#extra').vibrate({
    speed: 50,             // Vibration speed in milliseconds
    trigger: "mouseover",  // Triggering event
    reverse: true,         // Reverse behaviour
    overEffect: "stop",    // Over effect, see details below
    vibrateClass: "",      // CSS class applied when vibrating (New in vers. 1.1!)
    overClass: ""          // CSS class applied when over effect is triggered (New in vers. 1.1!)
});
```